# SteamCMD alternative for ARM CPU

Tags: linux, arm

I've got an OCI free tier 4 Core 24 GB ram instance. I ran modded minecraft server and it is very smooth. I want to go one step ahead and create server for any valve game such like GMod or CS:GO. As far as I know SteamCMD can be run only on amd or intel cpus. So is there any alternative for ARM architecures cpus? I know I can virtualise it with QEMU but it's hard and it also kills efficiency.

Comment: Even if you manage to get SteamCMD running, I don't think there are ARM builds of the server executables for Garry's Mod or CS:GO. If QEMU isn't efficient enough for your needs, Box86/Box64 or FEX might be options worth looking into.